# SQL find elements A not containing elements B and containing elements B with specific status

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have boxes, and items that can be contained in the boxes. Both boxes and items have a status. Boxes statuses are for example packed, unpacked, sent, received etc - an integer. Items statuses are scanned, not scanned and unknown (null) - a Boolean.

Or as tables:

- Boxes: [pk] int id, int status
- Items: [pk] int id, int
  box_id, boolean status

So, a box can have many items, but an item can only be contained in one box.

As a start, I want to be able to find all boxes with status = 0 that contains either no items at all or only items with status false and/or null. In the end, I want to change the status of all the matching boxes to 1.

Sample data and expected data:

boxes [pk] int id, int status, character(20) test_text

```
0;0;"(no items)"
1;0;"(items with false)"
2;0;"(items with null)"
3;0;"(items with null and false)"
4;0;"(items with true)"
5;0;"(items with true and false)"
6;0;"(items with true and null)"
7;0;"(items with true and false and null)"
8;1;"(no items)"
9;1;"(items with false)"
10;1;"(items with null)"
11;1;"(items with true)"
```

items [pk] int id, int box_id, boolean status

```
0;1;false
1;2;null
2;3;false
3;3;null
4;4;true
5;5;true
6;5;false
7;6;true
8;6;null
9;7;true
10;7;false
11;7;null
12;9;false
13;10;null
14;11;true
```

expected - boxes [pk] int id, int status, character(20) test_text

```
0;0;"(no items)"
1;0;"(items with false)"
2;0;"(items with null)"
3;0;"(items with null and false)"
```

I can't quite figure out how to write the proper code to do this. I'm using postgresql.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @jarlh I added data and results now... (hoping I didn't make any mistakes) :-)

Comment: The format in which you present the table structure and contents is not usable for people who want to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @joop How then? I changed it now, so it is presented the same way as when I copy+paste from the database (postgresql)

Comment: `boxes [pk] int id, int status, character(20) test_text` will cost a few minutes of editing to get it into usable form. Five or ten people will spend ~15 minutes just to reconstruct your structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select bb.id 
from boxes bb
    left join items ii on ii.box_id = bb.id
where bb.status = 0
group by bb.id
having sum(case when ii.status = true then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: `SUM()` will return `NULL` when it does not encounter any rows (or only `NULL` values). Use `COUNT()` instead. Possibly with a `FILTER (WHERE ii.status)` clause (but the `CASE` expression is a good alternative for earlier PostgreSQL versions).

Comment: This seems promising! Gonna test it a little bit more first to be sure though :)

Comment: If not found any items we will have 1 record for box with item status = null. So, `sum(case...)` will be equal `0`. Query can be changed to use `cont`, I just have no data to check it.

Comment: @Shpionus ahh, right, the `CASE` smooths that out. But I generally tend to avoid `SUM(1)` for counting because the possibility of `NULL` results. Also that won't make use any index, while a `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ii.status)` may could, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This appears to work perfectly fine, so I'm going to stick with it. Thanks @Shpionus

Comment: No problem, @Marcus

Comment: Btw @Shpionus, just to understand it. The left join joins merges two tables: the left table that contains all boxes, the right table contains all items. The result here is all the boxes on the left plus all the boxes on the right that have items. Then, for all these boxes, we check that box status = 0 and that the sum of item statuses for each box = 0, which gives the final result. And boxes without items sums to 0 (I assume). Is this correct?

Comment: Also @Shpionus, isn't it possible to use EXISTS somehow as an alternative to case (or maybe sum)?

Comment: `And boxes without items sums to 0 (I assume)` - correct. You can use exists condition as in answer from Thorsten Kettner. Also you can try `having max(ii.status::int) != 1`. If question in performance - need check both cases on real data and play with indexes.

Answer (score 1):

> all boxes with status = 0

```
where boxes.status = 0
```

> either no items at all or only items with status false and/or null.

i.e. boxes that don't contain any item with status true

```
where boxes.id not in (select box_id from items where status = true)
```

The complete query:

```
select *
from boxes
where status = 0
and id not in (select box_id from items where status = true);
```

(The `NOT IN` clause can be replaced by a `NOT EXISTS` clause, if you prefer this. I prefer `NOT IN` for its simplicity.)